# An elliptic system? Or other type of equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Consider the problem
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}[l]
--\Delta_n u=f \textrm{ in }\Omega\\
-\Delta_m u=g\textrm{ in }\Omega\\
\textrm{s.t. Dirichlet or Neumann Boundary conditions}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $\Delta_n$ denotes the Laplacian operator in $n$ first coordinates of $u:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta_m$ in the last $m$ coordinates. Of course, if we consider the Neumann boundary, one might suppose the necessary conditions on the forcing terms $f,g$.

Do anyone know results concerning the existence and uniqueness of solutions for this kind of problem? Also, how to search this kind of problem?

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the origin of the problem?

Comment: Seems like it's a pair of Laplace/Poisson problems, perhaps with coupling depending on the boundary conditions.

Comment: you certainly need $\Delta_mf=\Delta_ng$